# Tkinter GUI with button - wanting to run a python script on the button

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I currently have a python tkinter gui working with a button and scrolledtext input box for the text to be displayed, currently I have it set up so when the button is pressed runs this command:

```
def clickstart():
      output = subprocess.run(['python', 'wlp1.py'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
      output = str(output.stdout, encoding='utf-8')
      Textbox.insert(1.0, output)
```

this works no worries until I try to compile it to one single .exe file.
My question is, can i import the python code from wlp1.py into the main wlp.py script so its already just 1 file prior to being compiled. here is the main script;

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import filedialog
import sys
import os
import tkinter.scrolledtext as tkst
import subprocess
import re

root = Tk()
root.title("WLP")
root.geometry("975x475")
root.configure(bg='#0c0c0c')
root.resizable(0,0)



def clickstart():
     output = subprocess.run(['python', 'wlp1.py'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
     output = str(output.stdout, encoding='utf-8')
     Textbox.insert(1.0, output)

Label1 = Label(root, text="WLP", bg="#0c0c0c", fg="#C0C0C0")
Label2 = Label(root, text="********************", 
bg="#0c0c0c", fg="#C0C0C0")
Label3 = Label(root, text="*********", bg="#0c0c0c", fg="#C0C0C0")
Button1 = Button(root, text="START", bg="#0c0c0c", fg="#C0C0C0", command=clickstart)  #)
Textbox = tkst.ScrolledText(root, width=85, height=10, bg="#0c0c0c", fg="#C0C0C0")

Label1.grid(row=5, column=5, pady=15)
Label2.grid(row=7, column=5, pady=15)
Label3.grid(row=85, column=0, pady=125)
Button1.grid(row=10, column=5, pady=15)
Textbox.grid(row=17, column=5)

root.mainloop()
```

And here is the second script (wlp1.py) id like to chuck into the main script (wlp.py);

```py
import subprocess
import re

command_output = subprocess.run(["netsh", "wlan", "show", "profiles"], capture_output = 
True).stdout.decode()


profile_names = (re.findall("All User Profile     : (.*)\r", command_output))

wifi_list = []

if len(profile_names) != 0:
    for name in profile_names:

    wifi_profile = {}

    profile_info = subprocess.run(["netsh", "wlan", "show", "profile", name], capture_output = True).stdout.decode()

    if re.search("Security key           : Absent", profile_info):
        continue
    else:
        wifi_profile["ssid"] = name
        profile_info_pass = subprocess.run(["netsh", "wlan", "show", "profile", name, "key=clear"], capture_output = True).stdout.decode()
        password = re.search("Key Content            : (.*)\r", profile_info_pass)
        if password == None:
            wifi_profile["password"] = None
        else:
            wifi_profile["password"] = password[1]
        wifi_list.append(wifi_profile) 

for x in range(len(wifi_list)):
    print(wifi_list[x])
```

Comment: You could use the `threading` module to run two separate processes in the same program. To do this, you would need to move everything from `wlp1.py` into a function inside `wlp.py`. There are plenty of questions and answers on Stack Overflow that have to do with the `threading` module.

Comment: What problem are you experiencing (or expecting) with having some of your code in a separate file?  *Every* solution for compiling Python code to a .exe supports that, as they would be utterly useless otherwise (you wouldn't be able to use any part of the standard library).

Comment: @jasonharper when compiling WLP.py ive tried a few different ways but         
       pyinstaller --noconfirm --onefile --add-data 
       "C:/Users/user/Desktop/exe/wlp1.py;."  "C:/Users/user/Desktop/exe/WLP.py"  will compilie it, but when the .exe is run and the button pressed nothing happens unless wlp1.py is in the same directory as wlp.exe . this is with the terminal behind the .exe still, with --windowed not even wlp1.py in the same directory will work, has to have the terminal (so no windowed) and wlp1.py for it to work at all, im trying to aim for just the 1 .exe and not 1 py aswell